# Tableau URL Action Filter add to Context

Tags: tableau-api

I have two dashboards, I am passing a URL filter to filter from one dashboard to another. I need to add the action url filter to context. can someone please help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean that you need the text of the url visible in the text of one of your columns?

Comment: @vizyourdata No. I am currently passing a filter from one dashboard to another, by providing the url to the dashboard that I want to go to and passing the filter via <filter_name>. I want that <filter_name> to be set to context. what the filter is basically representing IDs, so I need my dashboard to filter on IDs first before doing anything else.